# How to I find the location within a string where a match was found for a particular capture group?

Tags: python, regex

If I have some regex with multiple capture groups, say for example

```
m=re.finditer(r'( ([aeiou]) | ([^aeiou]) ))
```

and I want to find the positions of

everything returned by `group(2)`, how would I do this?

Code example:

```
iterator = re.finditer(r'([^aeiou])\1+|([^aeiou\s])',mystring)
    non_germinated_consonants = []
    for match in iterator:
        non_germinated_consonants.append(match.group(2))
    print non_germinated_consonants 

encode('accomplished')
```

would produce the output:

```
[None, 'm', 'p', 'l', 's', 'h', 'd']
```

How do I find the positions of these characters using only re library methods?

Comment: Your question will be more clear if you add a sample input and a desire output!

Comment: Okay - what is `mystring` and how does that output relate to *I want to find the positions of everything returned by `group(2)`* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you've got two groups, if you're only interested in non-vowels, than just make that your regex? Anyway, check if `match.group(2) is not None` and use `match.start()` to get the position, eg:

Note I've removed the extraneous spacing and parentheses from your regex.

```
import re

matches = re.finditer(r'([aeiou])|([^aeiou])', 'the quick brown fox')
pos = [m.start() for m in matches if m.group(2) is not None]
# [0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [`start` method](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) of the match object is for:

> **start**([*group*])
>
> Return the ind[ex] of the start ... of the substring matched by *group*